# How do i delete data using collection in magento ORM?

Tags: magento

Right now i am deleting data like

```
  $deleteCCL = Mage::getModel('crossdata/customccitem');
  $deleteCCL->load($itemId);
  $deleteCCL->delete();
```

Is there any way to delete data using collection like:

```
$rcc = Mage::getModel('crossdata/customccitem')->getCollection()->delete();
```

?

Thanks a lot,

Balan

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There isn't a handy group delete function so either add it to your collection or simply do it directly.

```
foreach ($rcc as $ccitem) {
    $ccitem->delete();
}
```

Comment: But this would delete each individually.  Wouldn't we want to be able to pipe an arbitrary collection's SQL into a DELETE so we can delete them all in one swoop?

Comment: @sparcksoft You are correct, which is why I originally said you need to "add [group delete] to your collection".

Comment: Note to self: RTF SO Answer properly :)  I implemented this today, but not as generically as I would have liked.  What I'd like to do is implement a delete method that you can pass an arbitrary $collection into.  But I'm not exactly sure how to do it b/c the adapter delete method just takes a $where argument, and you'd need to pass in a SQL snippet that could include where's, join's, having's, group's, etc.

Answer (score 4):

`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` (which extends `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`) provides a `delete()` method for collections if you have the ability to extend it.

However, it's implementation is basically the same as yours:

```
/**
 * Delete all the entities in the collection
 *
 * @todo make batch delete directly from collection
 */
public function delete()
{
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $k=>$item) {
        $this->getEntity()->delete($item);
        unset($this->_items[$k]);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: love the `@todo` in the docblock! :)

Answer (score 3):

To implement delete functionality into a collection you have to add a new method to the collection class or a custom abstract class the collection inherits from.

**Example:**

```
public function delete()
{
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $key => $item) {
        $item->delete();
        unset($this->_items[$key]);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @leek, I got mine working:

```
foreach( $collection as $item )
    if( <<logic>> ) $collection->getEntity()->delete( $item );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  collection walk function

```
Mage::getModel('crossdata/customccitem')->getCollection()->walk('delete');
```

or each function

```
Mage::getModel('crossdata/customccitem')->getCollection()->each('delete')->clear();
```